# Convert paths to lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to convert black paths in image below to constant width lines. What strategy I should follow? 
[image]

Comment: Looks like you will need to use the pen tool and trace over it.

Comment: Vico, posting the same question over and over isn't going to make it any less of a duplicate.